# create web app that works on deskop and mobile

Tags: mobile, web-applications, desktop

i want to create a web app that works on a desktop and a mobile. i kinda have one at the moment but doesnt work on mobile well. Whats the best way around this? i know flash is being phrased out and java doesnt work on all mobile devices. I'm not not good with css, etc. This is current web app. http://www.acdcpowermonitor.com/Systemlive.aspx?systemid=1000000001&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1  i want it to just work on a webpage.

hope you can help

regards
jeremy

Answer (score 1):

you can make your web application responsive. bootstrap is a great tool to that with minimum css knowledge.

Comment: A little more details would be appreciated.

Comment: when we develop web application, we have to keep in mind that, all the application are now platform independent. If we use bootstrap for structured pre configured css . we can make responsive web appliaction. If we develop web site with bootstrap. we can control our view in various display like desktop, tab, mobile easily.

Comment: So your saying i could keep what i got and just add the bootstrap script to the page?

Comment: bootstrap has class for specific view. first know about bootstrap and its use. then add bootstrap file and use its class to fix responsive issues.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use bootstrap
Ref- https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_get_started.asp
And use eclipse if u want else Notepad++

Answer (score 0):

You can use 
**Bootstrap** 
Bootstrap is the most popular HTML, CSS, and JavaScript framework for developing responsive, mobile-first web sites.

Bootstrap is completely free to download and use!

latest version  `bootstrap@4.0.0-beta`

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/

and you can use for this

**Grid system**

this is a powerful mobile-first flexbox grid to build layouts of all shapes and sizes thanks to a twelve column system, five default responsive tiers, Sass variables and mixins, and dozens of predefined classes.

you can learn it

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

The Bootstrap grid system has four classes:

```
xs (for phones)
sm (for tablets)
md (for desktops)
lg (for larger desktops)
```

The classes above can be combined to create more dynamic and flexible layouts.

Tip: Each class scales up, so if you wish to set the same widths for xs and sm, you only need to specify xs.

look at https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp